# How to permanently change the default spelling dictionary?

Tags: text-editing, flyspell, spell-checking

In Aquamacs, the Emacs for macs, the dictionary can be changed in the Menu by going to Edit -> Spelling -> Change Dictionary...

In my case, I enter en_GB. How do I avoid doing this for every file again every time I open it? Where can I set this permanently as the default for all files?

I suppose I need to add a line in Preferences.el - but which one?

Neither of these two lines work

```
(setq ispell-dictionary "en_GB")

(setq ispell-dictionary "british")
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a variable called `ispell-dictionary`, whose docstring you can see with `C-h v ispell-dictionary` (note that you can use completion there, so this is a way to find variables named `ispell`-something).

> ispell-dictionary is a variable defined in ‘ispell.el’.
>   Its value is "francais"
>   Original value was nil
>
> Documentation:
>   Default dictionary to use if ‘ispell-local-dictionary’ is nil.
>
> You can customize this variable.

Click (or type enter) on the `customize` link to customize its value.  In the customize buffer, you will be able to change its value and save it through the `State` button.

Comment: I am confused. In my case it is indeed set to en_GB, but when I type "colour", it still shows an error, and when I type "color" it shows none. Is there a different dictionary for flyspell? Or is it the same?

Comment: I finally found out that on OSX, the operating system overrides the EMacs settings and checks the spelling with its own setting. Your answer was correct - thank you!